# Idioms for "letters being black marks for an illiterate"

Tags: idioms

There is an idiom in our native language  that translates **black letters are nothing more than buffaloes to an illiterate.**

Which means:   "To an illiterate person letters are nothing more than black marks."

Is there any such **idiom** in English?

Answer (score 1):

There is an expression (I believe coined by Shakespeare) that goes “It’s all Greek to me.” It means that you understand it so poorly that it may as well be a totally different language.

Comment: Can I also say "It's all Greek to him"?

Comment: "It's all Greek to me" refers to both spoken or written language, so wouldn't apply to an illiterate. "It might as well be hieroglyphics" works better.

Answer (score 0):

No idiom but the meaning of the expression seems perfectly clear (to me).  You could use it in  translation, perhaps saying

> As we say in my country,  "letters are nothing more..."